# Insert multi-page PDF as word pages

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, libreoffice-writer, google-docs

How do I insert a read-only, multi-page pdf into a word document as pages? PDF can contain graphics and might be hundreds of pages long.

Comment: You can use an OCR program for converting the PDF file to a Word document - some layout will get lost in this process. Alternatively you can export each page as picture and place those pictures in your word document.

Comment: @Robert OCR programs aren’t reliable at converting graphics. Exporting and resizing hundreds of PDF pages individually isn’t practical.

Comment: You can always merge the two documents into a single PDF and then reorder the pages.

Comment: @spike_66 This causes problems. Since if we convert the merged pdf back into word, the inserted graphics won’t be reliably converted. Unless of course we can somehow flag these pages to be converted to images.

Comment: There's a particular reason why the document has to be in a Word compatible format?

Comment: @spike_66 Yes, various clients specifically requests a .doc file format.